# Angular 2+: Difficulty in injecting services in constructor calls

Tags: angular, migration

I'm migrating the codebase of https://github.com/oppia/oppia from AngularJS to Angular 2+. We have a lot of services, about 300+. I migrated a filter [normalize-whitespace](https://github.com/oppia/oppia/blob/develop/core/templates/dev/head/filters/string-utility-filters/normalize-whitespace.filter.ts) to Angular 2+. Now, I was migrating the service [Validator Service](https://github.com/oppia/oppia/blob/develop/core/templates/dev/head/services/ValidatorsService.ts) which uses this filter.

```
import { AlertsService } from 'services/AlertsService';
import { AppConstants } from 'app.constants';
import { NormalizeWhitespacePipe } from
  'filters/string-utility-filters/normalize-whitespace.pipe.ts';
import { UtilsService } from 'services/UtilsService.ts';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidatorsService {
  private normalizeWhitespace: NormalizeWhitespacePipe = (
    new NormalizeWhitespacePipe(new UtilsService()));
  constructor(private alertsService: AlertsService) {}
```

This is the starting part of the Validator Service. The Normalize WhiteSpace filter depends on UtilsService and hence I need to pass that as a constructor argument since its injected in the filter. The question is if UtilsService too depends on other services say A and B, and A depends on others services and so on, don't you think the initialisation of `normalizeWhitespace` would be too difficult!

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have problems with cyclic dependencies or does your code not work? You should inject the UtilsService like the alertsService and create the NormalizeWhitespacePipe inside of the constructor.

Comment: I don't have any problem here but there could be potentially a problem somewhere in future where we have long constructor calls like `new NormalizeWhitespacePipe(new UtilsService())`. Think if UtilsService also depends on other services. I get the answer, we should not construct instances like this, instead we should inject into the constructor -- the injector will take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this

```
  private normalizeWhitespace: NormalizeWhitespacePipe = (
    new NormalizeWhitespacePipe(new UtilsService()));
```

in order to initialize a service.

It's quite simple: you just need to **declare all the dependencies always in the constructor** (as you are doing with `AlertsService`), then **angular will inject to each service what is needed based on that**.

Just make sure that all the services that should be globally available are provided in the root app.module, as you are doing with ValidatorsServices with

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Here's the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#services-that-need-other-services).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful. Yes, I've added providedIn:root over all services so that they are available globally. Though, why do we need to inject all the dependencies in the constructor? -- my guess is so that we don't have to write all the dependencies by ourselves (as I'm doing for the normalizeWhitespacePipe). Let me know the correct answer.

Comment: @NitishBansal yes, basically if all the services are available in the same scope (e.g. root) angular auto-resolve all the dependencies written in the constructor. If you have a service A that depends on B and B depends on C, angular will inject C in B and then B in A.